# Else If Not Work in PDO Script

Tags: php

I wanted to thwart POST if the number of characters entered is less than 6 use this code:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['button']))
    {
    $id = $_SESSION['user_session'];
    $u_password = $_POST['password'];

    if($crud->updatePassword($id,$u_password))
    {
        $msg = $msgsucces;
        }
    else if($u_password < 6) {
    $msg = "<div class='alert alert-warning'><strong>Failed!!</strong> Minimum length 6 character</div>"; 
    return false;
    }
        else
        {
        $msg = $msgfailled;
        }
}
    echo $msg ;
?>
```

But apparently it did not work. What is wrong?

Comment: `else if($u_password < 6)` you're missing a function here, `strlen()`. and check for errors. Lots of missing code here and a lot of unknowns to boot.

Comment: Don't you think length checking should be performed before `$crud->updatePassword($id,$u_password){ ...` ?

Comment: it would be a cool language that could guess you wanted to count the length here

Comment: Addition no need to use return false if u r using echo $msg at the end

Comment: Don't the cool kids do that? @Dagon

Comment: `$msgfailled` and `$msgsucces` are undefined.

Comment: @chris85 Just like I said: *missing code/unknowns* ;-)

Comment: Another thing, not absolutely sure, but this _looks like_ you store a password in a database. That is something one should _never_ do, that is _not_ if that password is used to authenticate against the system that stores the password. What you store is a _hash_ of a password. Not the plain password, not an encrypted password, but a good and robust _hash_ of the password. Then later, for authentication, you again hash the specified password and compare that hash to the one stored inside the database. That ensures that even if your site gets compromised no passwords get out.

Comment: Allow users to use the [passwords / phrases](https://xkcd.com/936/) they desire and [don't limit passwords](http://jayblanchard.net/security_fail_passwords.html)

Comment: Please use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: [*and to think I could have cashed-in big time Sam*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35418061/else-if-not-work-in-pdo-script#comment58536874_35418061) - @JayBlanchard

Comment: *You sure could've Ralph!* @Fred-ii-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use your conditions as like that:

```
$msg = "";
if(strlen($u_password) < 6) { 
    $msg = "<div class='alert alert-warning'><strong>Failed!!</strong> Minimum length 6 character</div>"; 
} 
else{
    if($crud->updatePassword($id,$u_password)) 
    { 
        $msg = "success message"; 
    } 
    else { 
        $msg = "failure message"; 
    }
}
echo $msg;
```

For checking length of an input you can use [`strlen()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php) function.

**Side note:**

Note that I have remove return false from ist condition.

Also suggest you to always add `error_reporting()` in your file this will help you to save your time. (Only for local environment not for production).

Comment: This code work for me. Thank you sir

Comment: @norax glad to help u. I suggest u to also check all comments which is more important for yur learning.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I need to understand longer to get bits and pieces, so I have not had time to send feedback

Answer (score 1):

1. with `$u_password <6` you are not really checking length.
2. You need strlen function to get the length and compare to 6 so we use strlen function
3. Rule of thumb is you should have wrong cases before the write one.
4. The last else is executed if `$crud->updatePassword($id,$u_password)` fails ie false.

   ```
          if(strlen($u_password) < 6) 
          {
               $msg = "<div class='alert alert-warning'><strong>Failed!!</strong> Minimum length 6 character</div>"; 
               return false;
          }
         else if($crud->updatePassword($id,$u_password))
         {
             $msg = $msgsucces;
          }
        else {
             $msg =$msgfailled;
           }
     }
   echo $msg ;
   ?>
   ```

Comment: @JayBlanchard I feel that explanatiion should be enough

Comment: Thank you for responding, now it can be used